# Hide or show specific DIVs

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have two DIV's. One has a list and the other has a collections of DIV's.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a>One</a></li>
        <li><a>Two</a></li>
        <li><a>Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Some content one</div>
    <div>Some content two</div>
    <div>Some content three</div>
</div>
```

When I click on the hyperlink 'One', I want to show the first DIV(Some content one) and hide all the other DIVs. When I click on the hyperlink 'Two', I want to show second DIV(Some content two) and hide all the others. How can I accomplish this using arrays in jQuery? Any other method is fine too.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of this online.  Numerous tutorials using Jquery.http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHEcKmoMBZo  here's one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('li').click(function() {
    var which = $(this).index();
    $('div').find('div').hide().eq(which).show();
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4KhUb/)

Answer (score 2):

What the heck:

```
$('a')​​.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div>div').eq($(this).closest('li').index()).show().siblings().hide();
})​;​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PmNku/)

Answer (score 1):

change a little your html:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><span data-showclass=".show_1">One</span></li>
        <li><span data-showclass=".show_2">Two</span></li>
        <li><span data-showclass=".show_3">Three</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="swichDiv">
    <div class="show show_1">Some content one</div>
    <div class="show show_2">Some content two</div>
    <div class="show show_3">Some content three</div>
</div>
```

and then jQuery:

```
$('ul li span[data-showclass]').click(function(){
  $('#swichDiv .show').hide().filter($(this).data('showclass')).show();
});
```

Comment: There is no need for extra attributes; check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to give the div's and the anchors corresponding id's and class

Check this .. It can still be optimized

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="wrapper1">One</a></li>
        <li><a id="wrapper2">Two</a></li>
        <li><a id="wrapper3">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="wrapper1" style="display:none">Some content one</div>
    <div class="wrapper2" style="display:none">Some content two</div>
    <div class="wrapper3" style="display:none">Some content three</div>
</div>​
```

**Javascript**

```
$('[id^="wrapper"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.wrap > div').hide();

    $('.'+ this.id).show();
});​
```

[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/6GvE6/1/)

Comment: There is no need for extra attributes; check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-line for unique row.

```
// show hide in jquery
$('.showdata').hide(); // hide all on start

$('.showhide').click(function (e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    var SH = this.SH ^= 1; // "Simple toggler"
    $(this).text(SH ? 'Hide' : 'Show')
    var id = event.target.id; // get id 
    //alert(event.target.id);
    $('#data' + id).toggle(); // show this one
});



<p><span class="showhide" id="1">Show</span>&nbsp;<span class="showdata" id="data1">content1</span> </p>

<p><span class="showhide" id="2">Show</span>&nbsp;<span class="showdata" id="data2">content2</span> </p>
```